# RTSP to RTMP using FFMPEG on Raspberry Pi to YouTube Livestream ends prematurely (and sometimes doesn't start)

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, rtsp, rtmp

I have been running a program from my raspberry pi 4 that converts a RTSP network camera feed to RTMP for YouTube. The stream used to run non-stop every day. I didn't have to do anything. I have a program in place that would restart if the feed died.

Nothing has changed with that program in ~2 years. About a month ago, the feed stopped working. I just started into trying to figure out why. Maybe someone has some ideas on what is going on?

In order for me to start the feed, I must also start a studio.youtube.com browser session showing the feed information. If that web page is up and running, the live stream will start. While I can't say for certain that it NEVER starts without this session running, it seems that way.

Usually the stream lasts for an hour or two. Rarely more than four hours.

When I start up a studio.youtube.com session after the stream dies the "Dimiss" or "Edit in Studio" message is on the page. I have to hit "dismiss" before I can start up the stream again.

Is there a solution to this?

Again, my program didn't change, so I'm at a loss for what I can do to fix this.

Comment: I don't understand why you need a browser session or why you even need to use studio.youtube.com instead of just getting the output URL with stream key.

Comment: That's my confusion as well. I currently have an FFMPEG session running 24/7 from a Raspberry Pi 4. The feed in very stable. The only way to get YouTube Live to recognize that the stream is live is to start Studio.